# Can I point Gummi to use TeX instead of LaTeX?

Tags: plain-tex, gummi

[gummi](/questions/tagged/gummi) is a great text editor since it has continuous re-fresh.  Can I link it to TeX instead of LaTeX?  Here is why: Some commands only work with TeX and not LaTeX.

```
me@Lenovo:~/Documents$ latex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 2 languages loaded.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \cleartabs
               % Nullify any previous \settabs.
? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Now let's try with TeX

```
me@Lenovo:~/Documents$ tex test.tex
This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/Debian) (preloaded format=tex)
(./test.tex [1] )
Output written on test.dvi (1 page, 544 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Gummi is open source so anything should be possible.

Comment: Gummi itself doesn't seem to give you the option of calling Tex Directly... but some of the relevant lines on Github are here https://github.com/alexandervdm/gummi/tree/master/src/compile

Comment: So it is a TeX document which uses the `plain` format rather than `latex`? I mean, some macros are defined in the former but not the latter, and some in the latter but not the former. They are both built on TeX, though.

Comment: @cfr I am reading through "TeX for the impatient" and just copied some lines and it didn't work...  In order to get Gummi to compile I inserted `\documentclass{beamer}\begin{document}` then my test code and `\end{document}`

Comment: That would be `plain`, then, rather than `latex` format. So, yes, you want to compile with `tex` or `pdftex`. Note that the output you posted shows that you've compiled differently along 2 different dimensions in the 2 cases: both the engine and the format change. In case one, you are using pdfTeX (engine) + LaTeX (format); in case two, TeX (engine) + plain (format). If you want PDF rather than DVI, you can compile with `pdftex` rather than `tex` and you'll still get the `plain` format, but PDF rather than DVI. [Technically, `tex` is probably pdfTeX in 'DVI' mode these days, in fact.]